# android twitter 4j 2.2.1 get media entities

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter4j

I am working on a twitter application using twitter 4j . Everything working fine except media files url not fetching along with status. I have searched a lot and twitter 4j 2.2.3 have a function for Media Entities.Url entities are availabe and How can i get Media entities using twitter 4j 2.2.1 .

Answer (score 1):

twitter4j is opensource, if you don't want to upgrade to the new version, you could modify the source code your self to satisfy your requirement.